# Why my second activity of the app is getting crashed?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[it shows logcat detail. its empty][1]After connecting my firebase database my app is getting crashed. Based on knowledge what I have seen in tutorial how to add firebase database to app. I connected my app, but im not sure why app is getting crashed and whether my app is linked with database or not. I have three activity here among that 2nd and 3rd have user detail that need to be send to database. But now the second activity is getting crashed i dont know about 3rd.
Even my logcat is not showing any details.
This is my 2nd activity java file:

```js
package com.example.admin.howdy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by admin on 01-Aug-18.
 */

public class second extends Activity{

    Spinner institute;
    RadioGroup type;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second);
        databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Feedbacks");
        Spinner sp=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        categories.add("Prince Dr K Vasudevan College of Engineering and Technology");
        categories.add("Prince Shri Venkateshwara Padmavati College of Engineering");
        categories.add("Prince Maticulation Higher Secondry School");
        categories.add("Prince Shri Venkateshwara College of Arts and Science");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(second.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,categories);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp.setAdapter(adapter);
        Button button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                sendUserType();
                Intent myintent2 = new Intent(second.this, third.class);
                startActivity(myintent2);
            }
        });
    }

   private void sendUserType()
{
    String usertypevar2="";
    String userinstitue=institute.getSelectedItem().toString();
    type = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    int id=type.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    if (id != -1) {
        RadioButton ex=(RadioButton)findViewById(id);
        usertypevar2=ex.getText().toString();
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Select An Option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    RadioButton ex=(RadioButton)findViewById(id);
    usertype up=new usertype(usertypevar2,userinstitue);
     databaseReference.setValue(up).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            System.out.print("Successful");
        }}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener()
    { public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        System.out.print("not Successful");
    } });;
    }
}
```

This is my 2nd activity xml file:

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="13dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
        android:text="Complete following steps to proceed further."
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display1"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="108dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
        android:text="Who are you?"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioGroup"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="114dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="13dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView4"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3">

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amita"
            android:text="Students"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amita"
            android:text="Staffs"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:fontFamily="@font/amita"
            android:text="Others"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="34dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/aladin"
        android:text="Which instution you belongs to?"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="249dp"
        android:layout_height="29dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:prompt="@string/app_name"
        android:spinnerMode="dialog"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="137dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorEdgeEffect"
        android:text="Next"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_editor_absoluteX="137dp" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my java class usertype:

```js
package com.example.admin.howdy;

/**
 * Created by admin on 08-Aug-18.
 */

public class usertype {
    private String usertypevar;
    private String userinstitute;

    public usertype()
    {

    }
    public usertype(String usertypevar,String userinstitute)
    {
        this.usertypevar=usertypevar;
        this.userinstitute=userinstitute;
    }
    public String getUsertype() {
        return usertypevar;
    }

    public String getUserinstitute() {
        return userinstitute;
    }
}
```

I have attache some of the error message from logcat window:

```
`08-11 18:28:56.771 19397-19397/com.example.admin.howdy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.example.admin.howdy, PID: 19397
                                                                     java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzEq()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in /data/app/com.example.admin.howdy-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                                         at com.example.admin.howdy.second.onCreate(second.java:36)
                                                                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
                                                                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)`
```

Comment: Did you put your second activity in your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: yes, I have already added all the activity.

Comment: Post your logs..

Comment: logcat is not showing anything.

Comment: Make sure you're not applying any filters to logcat.

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question and responde with @.

Comment: It's still not showing anything in log cat.... l already attach my logcat picture.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't initialize your radio group i.e. type.

Do like this:-

```
type = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
```

before

```
int id=type.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Update:-

```
int id=type.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
RadioButton ex=(RadioButton)findViewById(id);
```

These line can also result in a crash. As when the user presses the button without selecting any radio button the method getCheckedRadioButtonId() returns -1 and when you find the radio button using findViewById with id=-1 it will results in an null pointer exception causing the app to crash.

So, solution to this problem is you can add a check to detect if the id is not -1:-

```
int id=type.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

// If nothing is selected from Radio Group, then it return -1
if (id != -1) {
    RadioButton ex=(RadioButton)findViewById(id);
    String usertypevar2=ex.getText().toString();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this,"Please Select An Option", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Its still crashing.

Comment: Now check @PradeepAnand

Comment: nope its still crashing..... i have updated my code after ur suggestions.

Comment: Then try to log the output of onFailure() and see what you get:-

databaseReference.setValue(up).addOnFailureListner...

Comment: i have embedded the logcat picture. check it out.

Comment: @PradeepAnand I thing you have opened the wrong logcat. You have opened the emulators logcat and now you might be testing on the mobile. So, plz verify it. Are you currently running app on google pixel 2 emulator ??

Comment: yeah.... im running on google pixel 2 emulator. and how to do that onFailureListener().

Comment: databaseReference.setValue(up);
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                // Write was successful!
                // ...
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                // Write failed
                // ...
            }
        });

Comment: and yeah for that above comment as u have told that i opened emulator logcat... so what i should do to open my app logcat. As im new to this, ur help is really appreciated.

Comment: As you can see in the image posted by you on left side there is a drop down arror at Emulator Pixel_2_API_22. Click on arrow to change the device @PradeepAnand

Comment: Then instead of log try to toast the error of onFailureListener() @PradeepAnand.

Comment: That is due to the older versions of firebase dependencies. Try to change you dependency versions to latest one @PradeepAnand

Comment: how to do that?@Raj

Comment: Change your dependencies in build.gradle file

Answer (score 1):

`type` is `null` in `sendUserType()`. Hence below code throws NPE.

```
int id=type.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

Comment: Its still crashing